# How to design redux-saga and socket-io actions?

Tags: reactjs, redux, socket.io, redux-saga

I'm developing and `react-native` app using `socket.io` and `redux-saga`.
Working with [this](https://github.com/kuy/redux-saga-chat-example/blob/master/src/client/sagas.js) example,
I have created saga that listen to messages from the socket
and emit an action.

Now I wonder how to write the other side,
listen to `dispatch` events and `emit` them to the `socket`.
In the example, he used only 1 message for `write` events, so it's trivial.

I don't want my code to look like this:

```
yield fork(writeEvent1, socket)
yield fork(writeEvent2, socket)
yield fork(writeEvent3, socket)

...

function * writeEvent1 (socket) {
  while (true) {
    yield take(Actions.EVENT_1)
    socket.emit('event-1')
  }
}

function * writeEvent2 (socket{
  ...
}
```

How can I manage this `write` event in a readable way?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to modify the example to use more event names than just `message`. Dealing with that really depends on your use case. If you want to have a different event name for every message you can just modify the `write` saga to have a variable event name like so:

```
function* write(socket) {
  while (true) {
    const { eventName, payload } = yield take(SEND_MESSAGE);
    socket.emit(eventName, payload);
  }
}
...
yield put(sendMessage({eventName: 'foo', payload: { bar: 'baz'}}))
```

If you have a limited list of event names, you can still use the example above but possibly with some kind of const enum like:

```
const eventNames = {
    FETCH_USER: 'fetch-user',
    FETCH_ITEM: 'fetch-item',
    FETCH_POST: 'fetch-post',
}
...
yield put(sendMessage({eventName: eventNames.FETCH_USER, payload: { id: 123 }}))
```

Or if you want to differentiate only between very few kinds of event names then it makes sense to have an explicit write sagas like:

```
function* write(socket) {
  while (true) {
    const { payload } = yield take(SEND_MESSAGE);
    socket.emit('message', payload);
  }
}

function* writeError(socket) {
  while (true) {
    const { payload } = yield take(SEND_ERROR);
    socket.emit('error', payload);
  }
}
```

Comment: As for your first suggestion, if I go this path I'll have to modify the `reducers` in a way that they have to do some kind of `switch-case` to pick the right event. Now I have a map of events names and the corresponding reducer which is very comfortable (I'm using this boilerplate https://github.com/infinitered/ignite-ir-boilerplate-andross)

Comment: So you want to based on one dispatched actione update both the redux state through reducers and emit a message through websockets. Both using the same payload?

Comment: I was wondering maybe redux-saga have some solution for this, like the subscribe example